# SQL SERVER: Left join and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This should be simple on MySQL but I'm confused why SQL Server 2008 makes it imposible to do so.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers AS cust
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Vehicles AS v WHERE v.CustNo=cust.CustNo) AS veh ON veh.CustNo=cust.CustNo;
```

The error is

```
The multi-part identifier "cust.CustNo" could not be bound.
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach using `row_number()`:

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by cust.custno order by v.custno) rn 
    FROM Customers cust
        LEFT JOIN Vehicles v ON v.CustNo=cust.CustNo
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you please explain its difference in contrast to LEFT JOIN and OUTER APPLY?

Comment: @BoboFilipino -- the key to this approach is really `row_number`.  Using it with `partition by` and then filtering by `rn = 1` only selects the first `vehicle` record per `custno`.  the `outer join` is only needed if not all customers have vehicles.  if they do, you can use a standard `inner join` instead.

Comment: Ah, that's enlightening. I can think of ways that this would really be helpful on my current project. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and for genuinely being helpful. Upped and accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers cust LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Vehicles v
      WHERE v.CustNo = cust.CustNo
     ) veh
     ON veh.CustNo = cust.CustNo;
```

I am not aware of any database that would allow the correlation clause in the subquery.  You *can* accomplish this using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers cust OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Vehicles v
      WHERE v.CustNo = cust.CustNo
     ) veh;
```

Comment: Seems to be working. Thank you. Can you explain further?

Comment: I'm not sure what needs explaining.  You can basically do what you want in the original question by using `APPLY` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: @BoboFilipino . . . I would like to note that these versions should be more efficient than the `row_number()` version, with the appropriate indexes.